# Exception: Invalid argument for variable in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to link a Google Sheets file with a Google Doc file and replace the text of the Google Docs with some custom items.

```
Exception: Invalid argument: sheet
autoFillGoogleDocFromForm   @ Code.gs:5
```

This error is generated by the following code. I used (name of sheet), (file id inserted), (folder id inserted) instead of showing the actual values.

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {

    var activateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(activateSheet.getSheetByName('(name of sheet)'));

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var row = e.range.getRowIndex();
    var timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('(file id inserted)'); 
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('(folder id inserted)');
    var copy = file.makeCopy('' + timestamp, folder); 
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    var header = doc.getHeader();

    header.replaceText('{{TIMESTAMP}}', timestamp);
    doc.saveAndClose(); 

}
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it worked. Did you check your project settings? Is Sheets API enabled?

Comment: @mertdökümcü Sheets API isn't enabled, I don't really know how to enable it

Comment: Can you check the answer below?

Comment: @mertdökümcü yeah sorry I just saw it. So I added Sheets to the Services on the left hand side and it still is coming up with the same error

Comment: Is it for the same line or for another line? You should also add other APIs like Drive and Docs

Comment: @mertdökümcü yeah its for the same line. I added the Drive and Doc APIs just to be safe and it still keeps on coming up with the same error

Comment: I managed to re-populate your error. It occurs when script tries to get a non-existing sheet. Example: If the tab in your Google Sheets file is named different than the value you use in your function, it throws this error. Is your sheet/tab name the same with the one you use in your code?

Comment: Yeah they're both the same, I have screenshots if you want to see them basically of everything

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the way you define a [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('name of the sheet')
```

Even if you are not going to use the [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object any more, you can directly define the [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('name of the sheet')
```

Make sure you write the name of the `sheet` properly.

Comment: I tried this but it came up with this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
autoFillGoogleDocFromForm @ Code.gs:6"

Comment: This error means that `e` is undefined. `e` is the variable that represent the `event` that trigger the function, you can't run the function directly from the script editor. If you add more context about your scenario and what are you trying to get, it would be easy to help you.

Comment: So what i am trying to do is something to help file my ancestry and print it out in docs and folders so basically what i am trying to do is make it so each time i submit something to the google form i created for my ancestry it will be directed to a spreadsheet which automatically copies and fills out a doc which is then placed in a different folder based on a surname, and make the name the of the new doc "Family Of (my ancestor)" + an id i created

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look to [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). Then, you can start designing your project. By the way, why do you want to send the information collected by the Form to the Spreadsheet if it only `automatically copies and fills out a doc`? Maybe you can send directly that data to the Doc, or to both.

Comment: With this I just want to say, develop your project a bit further and when you encounter a more specific challenge, ask for help and I will be happy to give it to you.